# python3.2 ERROR on aix6.1

Tags: python, build, compilation, aix

i compiled python3.2 on aix6.2 server, but it doesnt work. Pop error like this

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
UnicodeEncodeError: 'filesystemencoding' codec can't encode character '\uda18' in position 28: Invalid wide character
IOT/Abort trap(coredump)
```

Any help is welcome.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

/home/hei/bin>echo LANG:$LANG LC_CTYPE:$LC_CTYPE

LANG:Zh_CN.gbk LC_CTYPE:

/home/hei/bin>export LANG=en_US.utf-8 && ./python3
Could not find platform independent libraries 
Could not find platform dependent libraries 
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:]
==================codeset[ISO8859-1]
==================CODESET[]

encoding[ISO8859-1]run _PyCodec_Lookup ERROR
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
UnicodeEncodeError: 'filesystemencoding' codec can't encode character '\uda18' in position 29: Invalid wide character
IOT/Abort trap(coredump)

/home/hei/bin>export LANG=en_US.utf-8 && export PYTHONHOME=. && ./python3
==================codeset[ISO8859-1]
==================CODESET[]
encoding[ISO8859-1]run _PyCodec_Lookup ERROR
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
UnicodeEncodeError: 'filesystemencoding' codec can't encode character '\uda18' in position 2: Invalid wide character
IOT/Abort trap(coredump)

Comment: What's the output of the command `locale -a` in your system? Basically, check the output, and use as the value for `LANG` one of the `.utf8` or `.utf-8` or `.UTF-8` locales.

Answer (score 2):

This might need a lot of step by step debugging, since I can't imagine where that surrogate character came from.

First, do the following in your shell:

```
$ echo LANG:$LANG LC_CTYPE:$LC_CTYPE
```

Please update your question with the output of this command.

I suggest you use an encoding that is UTF-8 (e.g `en_US.UTF-8`) if not already, and retry running Python.

It is also possible that the Python source code you have is not recent enough and is not patched for [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/893826) (which actually is [that](http://bugs.python.org/issue10955)) bug.

Comment: but the problem exists all the same

Comment: I see you used '.utf-8' instead of '.UTF-8'; not necessarily an issue, but please try again with 'UTF-8'.

Comment: it's so depressed, the error is still like this   
/home/hei/bin>export LANG=en_US.UTF-8  && ./python3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
==================codeset[ISO8859-1]
==================CODESET[]
encoding[ISO8859-1]run _PyCodec_Lookup ERROR
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
UnicodeEncodeError: 'filesystemencoding' codec can't encode character '\uda18' in position 29: Invalid wide character
IOT/Abort trap(coredump)